# C++: Get size of class instance

Tags: c++, class, sizeof

After writing a header and testing it (a lot), i wanted to know what the efficiency of this header was. What the header basically does is storing a map as efficiently as possible. Map.SetValue() stores a coordinate and Map.GetValue gets a coordinate. The coordinates get stored in a 2-dimensional vector, where four values get stored in one char (four possibilities per value).

I tried to get the size of the class by using this code:

```
int main()
{
    MapStorage Map;

    int Coords[2];
    int Value;
    int Size;
    float Efficiency;

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i += 1){
        for (int x = 0 + 10*i; x < 10 + 10*i; x += 1){
            for (int y = 0; y < 10; y += 1){
                Coords[0] = x;
                Coords[1] = y;
                Value = rand()%4;
                Map.SetValue(Coords, Value);
            }
        }

        Size = sizeof(Map);
        Efficiency = Size/float(i+1);

        std::cout << "Size at " << i+1 << " Square meters: " << Size << ", Effficiency: " << Efficiency << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

(MapStorage Map makes the class instance, as MapStorage is the name of the class)

But what happens is that this always prints that the size is 20 bytes, while at i = 99 the size should be at least 2,5kb (100 square meters, 100 values per square meter, 100*100 = 10 000, 4 values per byte, 10 000/4 = 2 500 bytes).

The question is: what am i doing wrong? do i not understand how sizeof works, or does it work differently with classes? I did some searching for other people with the same problem, but i couldn't find a solution that applies to my problem.

kind regards,
Harm

notes:
I store the map as a 2D vector of type unsigned char. it's not declared as static.

Comment: Please read the definition of `sizeof`, it will tell you why your assumptions are flawed.

Comment: What is `MapStorage`? Doing `sizeof(map)` will not give you the number of items in the map, only tell you the size of the object (which includes member variables and possible virtual table, and padding) nothing more. Why do you think e.g. [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) have a [`size()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/size) member function? If the term *size* means something else, like you seem to want it, why did you think the `sizeof` operator would automatically be able to calculate it from a user-defined type?

Comment: sizeof on pointer doesn't yield size of the pointee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do note that `sizeof` is a compile time, not runtime. The compile-time evaluated expression will be replaced by compiler with the outcome of `sizeof`. That's the reason, you could do this:

```
char bytes [ sizeof(int) ];
```

Which will be replaced as (if size of `int` on your compiler/platform is `4`):

```
char bytes [ 4 ];
```